# Passing multiple files using zcat and a for loop to a command

Tags: bash, find

I have a directory structure like this:

```
Y1/year1fileA.txt.gz
Y1/year1fileB.txt.gz
Y2/year2fileA.txt.gz
Y2/year2fileB.txt.gz
Y3/year3fileA.txt.gz
Y3/year3fileB.txt.gz
Y4/year4fileA.txt.gz
Y4/year4fileB.txt.gz
...
```

I was planning on passing the `<(zcat ./Y1/year1fileA.txt.gz ./Y2/year2fileA.txt.gz ...)` in that order into another command that expects `FILE` and not `stdin`.

I thought of using:
`command <(find . -name "*fileA*.gz" -exec zcat {})`

After running it, I realized the files where not passed into zcat in a sorted fashion (i.e. `year4fileA.txt.gz` was written before `year1fileA.txt.gz`)

Is there a way to use `find` and sort these files before passing to `zcat`? Or should I use for loops? or `xargs`?

Comment: `command <(zcat */year*.txt.gz)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`find` doesn't sort its output, but globs do. A glob that matches all of the files at once ought to suffice:

```
cmd <(zcat Y*/year*file*.txt.gz)
```